# How to clean the data from CSV file

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

The Sample name.csv data :

```
Name, ,Age, ,Class,
Diwakar,, ,25,, ,12,
 , , , , ,
Prabhat, ,27, ,15,
Zyan, ,30, ,17,
Jack, ,35, ,21,
```

reading the csv file:

```
names = spark.read.csv("name.csv", header="true", inferSchema="true")
names.show()
```

getting this as a output and we are loosing some data:

```
+-------+----+---+---+-----+----+
|   Name|   1|Age|  3|Class| _c5|
+-------+----+---+---+-----+----+
|Diwakar|null|   | 25| null|    |
|       |    |   |   |     |null|
|Prabhat|    | 27|   |   15|null|
|   Zyan|    | 30|   |   17|null|
|   Jack|    | 35|   |   21|null|
+-------+----+---+---+-----+----+
```

I want to have an output like given below:

```
+-------+---+---+---+-----+----+
|   Name|  1|Age|  3|Class| _c5|
+-------+---+---+---+-----+----+
|Diwakar|   | 25|   |   12|null|
|       |   |   |   |     |null|
|Prabhat|   | 27|   |   15|null|
|   Zyan|   | 30|   |   17|null|
|   Jack|   | 35|   |   21|null|
+-------+---+---+---+-----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

We can read all the fields by defining **`schema`** and then use the `schema` while reading CSV file then use **`When Otherwise`** we can get the data for **`Age,Class`** columns.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

#define schema with same number of columns in csv file
sch=StructType([
    StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Age", StringType(), True),
    StructField("3", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Class", StringType(), True),
    StructField("_c5", StringType(), True),
    StructField("_c6", StringType(), True)
])

#reading csv file with schema
df=spark.read.schema(sch).option("header",True).csv("name.csv")

df.withColumn('Age', when(length(trim(col('Age'))) == 0, col('3')).otherwise(col('Age'))).\
withColumn('1',lit("")).\
withColumn('3',lit("")).\
withColumn('Class',when((col('Class').isNull())|(lower(col('Class')) == 'null'), col('_c6')).when(length(trim(col('Class'))) == 0, lit("null")).otherwise(col('Class'))).\
withColumn('_c5',lit("null")).\
drop("_c6").\
show()

#+-------+---+---+---+-----+----+
#|   Name|  1|Age|  3|Class| _c5|
#+-------+---+---+---+-----+----+
#|Diwakar|   | 25|   |   12|null|
#|       |   |   |   | null|null|
#|Prabhat|   | 27|   |   15|null|
#|   Zyan|   | 30|   |   17|null|
#|   Jack|   | 35|   |   21|null|
#+-------+---+---+---+-----+----+
```

Comment: in my case it has 150 columns .....is there any other way to deal with the problem of (,) in data